# Is there a way to write openpyxl rows (stored in a list) into a new Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I open up two workbooks. Currentwb is empty. The activewb is full of rows and rows of data spanning multiple columns.

```
currentwb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Empty.xlsx')
activewb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Stuff.xlsx')
currentsheet = currentwb.active
activesheet = activewb.active
```

I have an empty list.

```
stuff = []
```

In my program I use a loop to append rows from the activewb into this list.

```
stuff.append(activesheet[i])
```

Now I have a list of items (there are 2 in the ex provided below).

```
[(<Cell 'Active'.A2>, <Cell 'Active'.B2>, <Cell 'Active'.C2>, <Cell 'Active'.D2>, <Cell 'Active'.E2>)(<Cell 'Active'.A5>, <Cell 'Activee'.B5>, <Cell 'Active'.C5>, <Cell 'Active'.D5>, <Cell 'Active'.E5>)]
```

How do I copy each row (values and all) onto the new Excel sheet (currentwb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write rows into lists and append into bottom of sheet